# Sort nested table with lua

Tags: sorting, lua, lua-table

I have following table:

```
{
  STANDBY = {
    timeout = "10",
    mode = "0"
  },
  RTP = {
    minport = "10000",
    maxport = "10010"
  }
}
```

I want to sort it alphabetically, so the resulting table should be something like this:

```
{
  RTP = {
    maxport = "10010",
    minport = "10000"
  },
  STANDBY = {
    mode = "0",
    timeout = "10"
  },
}
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: Those are the same table. Your question doesn't make sense. Non-integer keys do not *have* an order in Lua.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting the following from [Programming in Lua : 19.3](http://www.lua.org/pil/19.3.html).

> A common mistake is to try to order the indices of a table. In a table, the indices form a set, and have no order whatsoever. If you want to order them, you have to copy them to an array and then sort the array.
>
> If you traverse a table with `pairs()`, the names appear in an arbitrary order. However, you cannot sort them directly, because these names are keys of the table.

The workaround is also mentioned on the same page.

```
local tableVarName = {
    STANDBY = {
        timeout = "10",
        mode = "0"
    },
    RTP = {
        minport = "10000",
        maxport = "10010"
    }
}
function pairsByKeys (t, f)
  local a = {}
  for n in pairs(t) do table.insert(a, n) end
  table.sort(a, f)
  local i = 0      -- iterator variable
  local iter = function ()   -- iterator function
    i = i + 1
    if a[i] == nil then return nil
    else return a[i], t[a[i]]
    end
  end
  return iter
end
for name, line in pairsByKeys(tableVarName) do
  print(name, line)
end
```

Comment: It prints: `RTP table: 0041A268
STANDBY table: 0041A208`, which obviously is not what OP whishes.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Using the same function recursively isn't that difficult. One can always check using `type( a ) == "table"` condition.